# How can i combine my external c++ dll into my c# exe to have it a single file?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am calling a function from my c++ dll in my csharp winform app, but I would like to know if there is a way to combine the external processFiles.dll into the .exe output to have a single file to ship. Here is the current code i am using to call the function, then using it on `Form1_Load`. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
[DllImport("processFiles.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void startActions()
```

It is currently included as an embedded resource, but no luck.

Comment: You could pack the dll into the executable but you'd have to extract it again before you use it

Comment: .Net doesn't work with statically linkable libraries it needs dlls. Just make sure you have an installer that also installs the required .Net framework if not already present on the target system too. (Copy deployment can be problematic)

Comment: There's ways you can do this by unpacking the dll but I'd strongly recommend you don't do that. Deploy the dll in a private assembly

Comment: Thank you all for the hasty responses. I will take all of these into thought. Thank you all for the help.